# Character Ellipsis when multiple textblocks are present in parent container in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have 2 textblocks in a parent container and I want ellipse to be shown after second textblock content when  container size is reduced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="This is the first TextBlock. " />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="This is the second TextBlock. " TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" />
</Grid>
```

Result:

[image]